# Проблема в вычислении постфиксного выражения с помощью стека

Tags: c++

Проблема в вычислении постфиксного выражения с помощью стека. Если кто-то может помочь с кодом, буду очень благодарен. Проблема в `cin >> operatr`, не знаю, как заменить.
Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int number;
    Node* prev = NULL;
};

struct Stack
{
    Node* end = NULL;
};

void push(Stack* stack, int value)
{
    Node* node = new Node;
    node->number = (value);
    node->prev = stack->end;
    stack->end = node;
}

int pop(Stack* stack)
{
    int value = stack->end->number;
    stack->end = stack->end->prev;
    return value;
}
int calculate()
{
    Stack values;
    int temp;
    int operatd;
    char operatr = 'N';

    while (1)
    {
        if (cin >> operatd)
        {
            if (operatr == 'N')
            {
                push(&values, operatd);
            }
            else if (operatr == 's' || operatr == 'S')
            {
                return values.end->number;
            }
            else
            {
                int temp = pop(&values);

                switch (operatr)
                {
                    case '+':
                        values.end->number += temp;
                        break;

                    case '-':
                        values.end->number -= temp;
                        break;

                    case '*':
                        values.end->number *= temp;
                        break;

                    case '/':
                        values.end->number /= temp;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (cin >> operatr)
        {
            if (operatr == 'N')
            {
                push(&values, operatd);
            }
            else if (operatr == 's' || operatr == 'S')
            {
                return values.end->number;
            }
            else
            {
                int temp = pop(&values);

                switch (operatr)
                {
                    case '+':
                        values.end->number += temp;
                        break;

                    case '-':
                        values.end->number -= temp;
                        break;

                    case '*':
                        values.end->number *= temp;
                        break;

                    case '/':
                        values.end->number /= temp;
                        break;
                }

                operatr = 'N';
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << calculate();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Поясните подробнее в чем проблема.

Comment: суть в тому что когда вводим с клавиатуры символ( + - * /) програма просто вылетаэт.

Comment: Пояснения нужно в вопрос добавлять. Что значит вылетает, падает чтоли?

Comment: да,останавливаэт роботу.

Comment: @GrandPa А почему у Вас по сути два огроменных одинаковых куска кода в программе? Не хотите ли как-то объединить всё это? Может тогда и программу отладить проще будет.

Comment: `pop` ведет к утечке памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Для получения одиночного символа есть функция `cin.get()`.

Но вообще вам просто нужно отделить котлеты от мух. Будет лучше если `calculate` будет принимать строку `std::string`, и обрабатывать её. А в main эту строку уже можно получить разными способами, в том числе просто вбить в коде. Тогда и ошибку проще найти будет.